# get posts and postmetas in assoc array

Tags: posts, wpdb, sql

how do I get all posts and postmetas in an associative array?

```
$allposts = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT $wpdb->posts.post_title, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key
FROM $wpdb->posts
JOIN $wpdb->postmeta 
ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.id
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status ='publish';", OBJECT_K);
```

I just don't get it....

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't do it in a single SQL query. You need two.

You don't have to make direct queries though, since you can use get_post() and get_post_custom().

Comment: hhmm..... but I would like to get all posts.. I thought get_post() is just for a specific one..

Comment: Right. When calling get_posts() or WP_Query, WP will automatically cache all the metadata, using a single query. You can then access it using get_post_custom() or get_post_meta() for each post.